# How do I decorate Fabric tasks with @roles when my tasks inherit from the Task class?

Tags: python, fabric

I have a number of tasks defined as Task subclasses and I have roledefs set similar to the following:

```
env.roledefs = { "web": ["1.2.3.4"], "db": ["5.6.7.8"] }

class Foo(Task):
  name = "foo"

  def run(self):
    pass

foo = Foo()
```

With the `@roles` decorator I can decorate tasks if they are functions in a module but I'm not sure how to apply this to Task classes. Decorating the class or its run function doesn't seem to work.

I'm using Fabric 1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you should be able to use the init it like:

```
def __init__(self):
     env.roles = ['web']
```

or use execute:

```
execute(foo, roles='web')
```

Comment: The first example doesn't work saying that the 'foo' task is not found when running from the command line. The second I'm not sure I can use since I don't want to execute the task right away, only when specified on the command line.

Comment: updated to suggest init and kept the other one for clarity's sake.

Comment: Setting the role in `__init__` appeared to work, although with the version I'm using I had to use `env.roles = ["web"]`. Is this how it's supposed to be done? I certainly can't find it in the docs. Thanks for your help @Morgan.

Comment: ah yeah, sorry, updated again. coding in browser is less then optimal.

Comment: I found that setting the `roles` attribute in the `Foo` class also works.